# Facing time complexity issue in josephus permutation in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

So I was writing the code for josephus permutation in python.It works for smaller ranges but when range is increased,it takes a lot of time to give output.The time complexity is O(n^2),can anyone tell me how I can reduce that?

Here's my code:

```
def solution(array,k):
    permutation = []
    index=0
    while array:
        index = (index+k-1)%len(array)
        permutation.append(array.pop(index))
    return permutation

people=8
arr=[p+1 for p in range(people)]
k=3
final=solution(arr,k)
print(final)
```

Answer (score -1):

def josephus_permutation(n, k):
permutation = []
index = 0

```
for i in range(n):
    index = (index + k - 1) % (n - i)
    permutation.append(index + 1)

    # Remove the selected element from the array
    del permutation[index]

return permutation
```

Comment: Your answer is lacking details. Tell the person asking what you are doing and perhaps the time complexity of your answer